# Combing two columns contents in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two columns that need to have their contents combine. I want the combining to occur on every row of form.

```
With Cells(PoleRow, 25) = Cells(PoleRow, 25).Value & " / " & Cells(PoleRow, 123).Value
End With
```

With this code, it does not error out but it also does not do anything. I want to combine everything in column 123 into column 25.

Comment: Do you want to combine the values in column 25 AND 123 or from 25 TO 123?

Comment: I want to combine the values in 25 and 123 and place them in 25. Thanks! @M.Getrost

Answer (score 1):

Try to make the code as simple as possible. E.g., write the left concatenated part to a string and pass the string to a value. Then it looks maintainable and eas to understand:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim poleRow  As Long
    poleRow = 1

    With Worksheets(1)
        Dim union As String
        union = .Cells(poleRow, 25) & " / " & .Cells(poleRow, 123)
        .Cells(poleRow, 25) = union
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You just can't do it in one lane :)

Earlier you should declare starting row and last row for which you want to iterate.

```
For PoleRow=1 to 125 '  decalring start row = 1 and last row, you can also declare last row by VBA code
With Cells(PoleRow, 25) 
Cells(PoleRow,25) = Cells(PoleRow, 25).Value2 & " / " & Cells(PoleRow, 123).Value2
End With
Next PoleRow
```

How to declare last row/coll: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba